# How to get the innerHTML of a XML document (AJAX)?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

After an AJAX query, a XML file is returned. I'm able to "parse" that file, but when it comes to getting the "innerHTML" (or in this case "innerXML") of an element, the issue arises.

If the XML element, let's say "content", only contained text I could do: `content.childNodes[0].nodeValue` (assuming that *content* references the XML element "content"). But that element contains other elements:

```
<stackoverflow reason="tribute to this page">
   <content>
      <div><span><p>Some more HTML elements</p></span></div>
   </content>
</stackoverflow>
```

I need to **copy** the content of `<content>` to an existing `<div>` in the page, how could I do that?

Ex. `myDiv.innerHTML = content.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a hack you should not use at all. Instead, use the normal [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/DOM3-Core.html) functions:

```
myDiv.appendChild(document.adoptNode(content));
```

Comment: +1, but note that `adoptNode()` and `importNode()` are not supported by Internet Explorer. Fortunately, [workarounds exist](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdfwkmx.php).

Comment: It works! However, when I "copy" a `<b>bold</b>` element, the style is not applied (text isn't bold). I know the `<b>` elements are deprecated...but it should still work...

Comment: @JCOC611, indeed, but it also creates a new element in the context of the target document and uses `innerHTML` on that element *before* adding it to the document tree :)

Comment: -1 for "innerHTML is a hack you should not use at all".

Answer (score 5):

Try placing the HTML within CDATA tags, like so:

```
<stackoverflow reason="tribute to this page">
   <content>
      <![CDATA[<div><span><p>Some more HTML elements</p></span></div>]]>
   </content>
</stackoverflow>
```

Then just insert the data into your element via `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = content.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Comment: I would like to know too. I was suggested to do this when I wanted to store an XML document within a Android resource file. I thought that this was a legitimate method. Then the content could be added via `innerHTML` which is cross browser unlike most of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use XMLSerializer to convert the xml node back to a string representation and then use innerHTML to copy it to the element:

```
div.innerHTML = 
  (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(content.childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```

However the solution pointed out by phihag looks to be the safer one. However, I did not test either, and I'm not sure about browser compatibility.

Comment: `XMLSerializer` is not supported in IE up to and including version 8, but is otherwise well-supported.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cloneNode` and `appendChild`:

```
myDiv.appendChild(content.childNodes[0].cloneNode(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use innerHTML, here is how to convert the XML markup for the first Element into a string

```
//Where oXML is the xml document or xml object
var XMLString;
oXML=oXML.getElementsByTagName('content')[0].firstChild;
//nodeType 1-Element,2-Attr,3-Text.....
while(oXML.nodeType!=1){oXML=oXML.nextSibling;}
//code for IE and Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc. respectively
XMLString=(oXML.xml)?oXML.xml:(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oXML);
myDiv.innerHTML=XMLString;
```

The while... is used to find the first element within the content tag, skipping text nodeType. 
Firefox adds the text nodeType, IE6 does not when no text is within the text node.