# Code works in Chrome on my PC but doesn't work in my devices

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am using Sencha Touch and trying to get data from a remote server.

Here is my store:

```
Ext.define('webTrak.store.NoiseStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['webTrak.model.noiseChunk', 'Ext.data.reader.Xml'],
    config:{
        autoLoad: true,
        storeId: 'NoiseStore',
        model: 'webTrak.model.noiseChunk',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            //url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwebtrak.bksv.com%2Fmel%2Fdata%2F46610526'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=",
            url: 'http://webtrak.bksv.com/mel/data/46611635',
            //url:'app/store/now.xml',
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                //rootProperty: 'results',
                record: 'data'
            }
        }
    }
  
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
 noiseStore.load({
            callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                myop = records;

                if (!success) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed!', records[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success!', $(records[0].raw).html());
                }

                //var lines = $(records[0].raw).html().split('\n');
                var lines = records[0].raw.innerHTML.split('\n');
                Ext.Msg.alert('number of lines', lines);


                Ext.Object.each(lines, function (key, value, myself) {
                    //window.setInterval(function () { }, 1000);
                    Ext.Function.defer(function () {
                        var fields = value.split(',');
                        var isNoise = fields[0];
                        if (isNoise === 'noise') {
                            console.log('noise = ' + fields[5]);
                            Ext.Msg.alert('noise', fields[5]);

                            var locid = fields[3];
                            var noisevalue = fields[5];

                            var overlayTmp = new Ext.Template('<div class="overlay">{noiseValue}</div>', { compiled: true });
                            overlayTmp.compile();
                            var overlayHtml = overlayTmp.apply({ noiseValue: noisevalue });

                            var tempOverLay = sensorSet[locid];
                            tempOverLay.onRemove();

                            sensorSet[locid].setValues({
                                content: overlayHtml
                            });

                            sensorSet[locid].onAdd();
                            sensorSet[locid].draw();
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('radar = ' + fields[10]);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                    //window.setInterval(function () {
                      
                    //}, 1000);

                  
                });

            }
        });
```

And this is the data source: http://webtrak.bksv.com/mel/data/46611635

How can I make it work in mobile devices as well?

### Update

After inserting many console.log() after many lines of code, I finally found where my code causes problems.

It is this line of code:

```
   var lines = records[0].raw.innerHTML.split('\n');
```

that causes the problems as all its following `console.log()` outputs are not printed out.

So I suspect that it's the `innerHTML` doesn't work in Windows Phone 8, I also tested the code, it doesn't work in Android (HTC Sensation XE) as well.

So my question is: what is the alternative of innerHTML in order to get the content of `records[0].raw`?

### Update 2

I follow Evan Trimboli's advice to use XMLSerializer and it works.
The only problem is:

```
var lines = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(records[0].raw).split('\n');
```

The `lines[0]` is `<data endTime="2014-04-25 00:17:59" generated="2014-04-26 22:24:34" handle="46611635" radarStatus="online" startTime="2014-04-25 00:17:30" type="data">noise,20140425001730,6,6,COMMUNITY_NOISE,40.8`.

As there is no '\n' between the closing tag of data and the beginning of the first line.

I could simply use `split('>')[1]` to get the wanted part, but that's not the best practice.

So my question is, how to get the content of the XML node?

(I guess it's could be hard, since the method "serializeToString()" has already converted the structured data to a string.)

Comment: Help with what? You didn't ask a question. You just dumped your code and said it isn't working.

Comment: hi @RUJordan I have updated my question, I want to make it work in deivces as well. thank you

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. You need to have a specific question. "make it work" is the most generic thing you could say.

Comment: current debug log would work so we can see how far the code execution goes. So far there's nowhere near enough information here to be able to help you.

Comment: Also, not sure if you're aware, but if you use safari on mac in development mode you can inspect any phonegap/cordova/web app running on your device from a mac. this would avoid the need to use Ext.Msg.alert in debugging.

Comment: hi @RUJordan, sorry for making a "blur" question. It was 4:30AM when I posted this question and my brain stopped working at that moment. Please see my updated question. Thank you.

Comment: hi @shepsii  Please see my updated question and let me know what information you need in order to help me. Thank you.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4630658/149436

Comment: hi @EvanTrimboli, thank you very much!!!! the XMLSerializer works!!! Only one minor issue, please see my update, thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about best practice if you have to deal with that terrible mess.

Comment: hi @EvanTrimboli, alright. Could you please post your reply as an answer? I'm going to set it as the answer of my question. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the innerHTML of a XML document (AJAX)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630611/how-to-get-the-innerhtml-of-a-xml-document-ajax)